# Enum to String in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this enumeration

```
Public Enum Applications
    Unknown = 0
    AA = 1
    BB = 2
    CC = 3  
End Enum


Private Const CALLING_APP As Applications= Applications.CC
```

CALLING_APP.ToString() is giving me "3". But I want "CC" - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are u sure? try something like `Dim s = CALLING_APP.ToString` what do u get?

Comment: see [MSDN examples and explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4). Just remember to switch the code example to VB in case this link does not do that.

Comment: See the "notes to callers" section. Simply calling ToString should return the name. If it does not, something other must be wrong. Try using precisely that example. What does it return? What's your VB/.Net version. I'm asking just in case. Is it ie in-Excel VBA or something?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Private CALLING_APP As Applications= Applications.CC    ' no "Const"
' CALLING_APP.ToString will return CC
```

`Const` can apparently change how NET recognizes the constant. As a Const, I get `Cannot find the method on the object instance` while Intellisense "sees" it correctly.  If you must use `Const` for some reason, you can get the text return this way:

```
Dim strName as string = [Enum].GetName(GetType(Applications), CALLING_APP ))
```

It is basically what .ToString does for us behind the scenes.  Typed as it is, your code should work.

Answer (score 4):

Pass "F" as parameter for the `ToString()` method: `CALLING_APP.ToString("F")`

Comment: that will give you "3.00"

Comment: @Plutonix Did you try it? [MSDN Refererence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It works for me even if it's a Const. Your variable is of type Object, but the variable in the question has the type of the Enum.

Comment: @alu yes, that makes a big difference!  I didnt see that he declared it as type.